# returning one of several objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I am collaborating on a dynamically generated web page that uses mustache and js to determine what to display. I want to have a function that returns one object given a certain global condition and a different object if that condition is not the case, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
getNameTokens: function() {
    var tokens;
    if(world.indexOf('9') == 1 ||world.indexOf('9') == 0) {
        tokens = {agent: 'president', ent: 'company', ownsf: 'the company\'s', owns: 'its'};
    } else {
        tokens = {agent: 'player', ent: 'player', ownsf: 'his', owns: 'his'};
    }
    return tokens;
},
'tokenNames': getNameTokens(),
```

Am I doing somthing wrong here?

Comment: What is inside *world* array and is it a global one? Is your code always returning one of the options and never the other one?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong exactly? Are you getting an error or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: the code is causing the page to not load. I'm a hobbyist rather than a pro so I'm doing this all in the browser.

Comment: You must get an error message in the developer console. That message is the key. Is it like `getNameTokens is not defined` or something?

Comment: the world array works in other functions and variables in the same invironment that this function is created and called in.

Answer (score 1):

Probability it should be something like this:

```
var world = [0,2,3,5,5,];

var getNameTokens = function(element) {
    var tokens = {};
    if(world.indexOf(element) <= 1) {
        tokens = {
          agent: 'president', 
          ent: 'company', 
          ownsf: 'the company\'s', 
          owns: 'its'
        };

    } else {
        tokens = {
          agent: 'player', 
          ent: 'player', 
          ownsf: 'his', 
          owns: 'his'
        };
    }
  return tokens;
}

var newObj = getNameTokens(0);
console.log(newObj)
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8t16d0wy/) example. Or It could be also as @Krystian Laskowski has described

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot invoke object method in this object literal. That is because an object literal is only a list of key/value pairs. It doesn't contain any instantiation logic (i.e. constructor).

I guess that the solution for your problem might be something like this:

```
function objectFactory(){
var getNameTokens = function() {
    var tokens;
    if(world.indexOf('9') == 1 ||world.indexOf('9') == 0) {
        tokens = {agent: 'president', ent: 'company', ownsf: 'the company\'s', owns: 'its'};
    } else {
        tokens = {agent: 'player', ent: 'player', ownsf: 'his', owns: 'his'};
    }
    return tokens;
}
var result = {
    getNameTokens: getNameTokens,
    tokenNames: getNameTokens
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is part of an object literal, like:

```
var world = '9876';
var Service = {
    getNameTokens: function() {
        var tokens;
        if(world.indexOf('9') == 1 ||world.indexOf('9') == 0) {
            tokens = {agent: 'president', ent: 'company', ownsf: 'the company\'s', owns: 'its'};
        } else {
            tokens = {agent: 'player', ent: 'player', ownsf: 'his', owns: 'his'};
        }
        return tokens;
    },
    'tokenNames': getNameTokens()
};
```

In this case, you can't just write `'tokenNames': getNameTokens(),`, as there is no `getNameTokens()` function in the
scope. There *will* be a `Service.getNameTokens()` function, but only after the object gets constructed. To use it during
the construction define it separately:

```
var world = '9876';
function getNameTokens() {
    var tokens;
    if(world.indexOf('9') == 1 ||world.indexOf('9') == 0) {
        tokens = {agent: 'president', ent: 'company', ownsf: 'the company\'s', owns: 'its'};
    } else {
        tokens = {agent: 'player', ent: 'player', ownsf: 'his', owns: 'his'};
    }
    return tokens;
}
var Service = {
    getNameTokens: getNameTokens,
    'tokenNames': getNameTokens()
};
```